# Finder tags not appearing in Save Dialog

Tags: finder, mojave, finder-tag, dialog

If I select an existing file with tags in the Save dialog, the Tags field is not showing any pre-existing tags. For example, the check.txt file in the dialog below is tagged (and sitting at ~/Desktop), but the tag does not appear in the dialog when I select the file.

[image: SaveAs Dialog no Tags]

I've seen this behavior across apps (Sublime Text, OmniGraffle), and it is happening on non-networked drives, which makes me think I've inadvertently done something on my system.

The files are tagged in the original Save Dialog, I'm not adding tags later. I've verified the tag with Get Info and the `mdls -raw -name kMDItemUserTags ~/Desktop/check.text` command.

Without having the pre-existing tags populated I need to remember the original tags or accept that I'm going to lose my tags on the file. Neither of these is really terribly satisfying.

I'm running 10.14.3.

Is there a CLI preference that might have disabled this ability or did mojave change the pre-population of this info?